# Selecting Item of Dictionary by Index # using VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, collections, dictionary

I am trying to load a combo box with the last item in a dictionary. I am trying to do something like this `ComboBox1.Value = NodeColl.Item(NodeColl.Count)` which would work with a collection, but does something strange when using a dictionary instead.

Comment: haven't tried stuff with a dictionary, but perhaps it's a zero based array - if so, the last item is `.count -1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behaviour is different because a Dictionary allows numeric keys.

Calling `.Item` actually *adds* an item with the given key so;

```
NodeColl.Item(NodeColl.Count)
```

Adds a new item with no value & a key corresponding to the count.

To access the ordinal item use `.Items` (which is an array of the items)

```
firstItem = NodeColl.Items(0)
lastItem  = NodeColl.Items(NodeColl.Count - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! As a follow-up, how would I be able to get the key of a specific item accessed by the above method?

Comment: Yep via .keys(); `msgbox "key for item 2 is " & NodeColl.keys(1) & " value is " & NodeColl.items(1)`

Comment: Thanks! As another follow-up (the last one I promise!) how would I get the item # of a specific key in a dictionary?

Comment: You would need to loop .keys() I think

Comment: Note that the above methods only work for early binding. If you try it in code that is late bound, you get Runtime Error 451: Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object.

Comment: However, a workaround is to write NodeColl.Items to a variant array like so:
var = NodeColl.Items
Debug.print var(0)